# Javascript and bookmarks

Tags: javascript, bookmarks

Lets say that I am on a page that has a significantly long list of URLs and I want to make sure that I have all of them bookmarked.  I know that I already have many of them in my bookmarks list and would like to avoid duplications as much as possible.

With that in mind, I would like to be able to grab all of the links and then open into new tabs those that are not currently contained in my bookmarks list.  I can do all of the getting the links, and comparing the links, I just don't know how to access the bookmarks via javascript.

I can do this in whatever PC/mac browser that has a workable solution.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will never be able to access the user's bookmarks via JavaScript. In fact, that would be a severe security hole.

JavaScript gets executed in a socalled sandbox. That means that, at least in theorey, a JavaScript never will have access to the resources of the client machine (in practice, the sandboxes have bugs that allow nasty things, but that is a different story).

Comment: So then my only option would be to host my bookmarks list on my server and create an AJAX type call that would send the url to a script on my server that would check for the bookmark?  I guess that doesn't sound too horrible.

Comment: If you want to stick to JS, that would be a solution. Of course there are Firefox Extensions like "Bookmark all", but these don't filter out duplicates. But you could use this https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/542 and this https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/1553 in combination, it could solve your problem :-)

Comment: Yeah, I only want to open the links that don't already exist in my bookmarks list, so AJAX might be the only way to do it.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also Check out Opera Link ;)

http://www.opera.com/link/

Filtering duplicates can be done on-line in your accout.

Comment: I looked at opera the other day and didn't like how I couldn't get the "personal bar" (the one with my bookmarks in it) to sit below the url/etc bar.  What's the deal with that?

Comment: Right-click on your personal bar -> Select Appearance -> Set Placement to bottom