# Is it possible to get bookmarks of the browser via Flash

Tags: flash, bookmarks

i want to know if it possible to access the browser bookmarks via Flash.

I know, that this is not possible via Javascript, but it maybe possible via Flash

thanks

Comment: No, for the same reason Javascript doesn't have access to bookmarks - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080943/javascript-and-bookmarks

Comment: I am curious as to why you would want to do this. AFAIK, you cannot do this, doing so would be a serious security risk, potentially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and allowing flash to do so would be a *major* security hole. Other than using flash to get at the bookmarks file, there is no other way.